# C# List1.Union(List2) - custom comparison

Tags: c#

I have two Lists, they look like this

`list1` contains

```
CMD=stopped|ID=1234|TS=2017-06-30 7:19:20|AUF=4711|AG=010|;
CMD=stopped|ID=1111|TS=2017-06-30 7:19:20|AUF=4711|AG=010|;
CMD=stopped|ID=2222|TS=2017-06-30 7:19:20|AUF=4711|AG=010|;
CMD=stopped|ID=3333|TS=2017-06-30 7:19:20|AUF=4711|AG=010|;
CMD=stopped|ID=4444|TS=2017-06-30 7:19:20|AUF=4711|AG=010|;
CMD=stopped|ID=5555|TS=2017-06-30 7:19:20|AUF=4711|AG=010|;
```

`list2` contains

```
CMD=stopped|ID=2222|TS=2017-06-30 8:19:20|AUF=4711|AG=010|Res=saguasgha|Mail=true|;
CMD=stopped|ID=6666|TS=2017-06-30 8:19:20|AUF=4711|AG=010|Res=saguasgha|Mail=true|;
```

Now I want to merge them into a new List, called `List3` **on the ID**. **List2 should replace entrys on List1 with same ID**, so expected result of `List3` is this:

```
CMD=stopped|ID=1234|TS=2017-06-30 7:19:20|AUF=4711|AG=010|;
CMD=stopped|ID=1111|TS=2017-06-30 7:19:20|AUF=4711|AG=010|;
CMD=stopped|ID=2222|TS=2017-06-30 8:19:20|AUF=4711|AG=010|Res=saguasgha|Mail=true|;
CMD=stopped|ID=3333|TS=2017-06-30 7:19:20|AUF=4711|AG=010|;
CMD=stopped|ID=4444|TS=2017-06-30 7:19:20|AUF=4711|AG=010|;
CMD=stopped|ID=5555|TS=2017-06-30 7:19:20|AUF=4711|AG=010|;
CMD=stopped|ID=6666|TS=2017-06-30 8:19:20|AUF=4711|AG=010|Res=saguasgha|Mail=true|;
```

I know I could achieve this with `List.Union` Method, but since this uses Hashcodes and the strings are different, its not working. So I just need the comparison of the `ID` - "Attribute" of the strings, nothing more.

I think I have to override `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()`, but dont know how to do so do obtain my goal.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

(For extracting the ID I have a Method which returns the ID-Value from a given string, its called `RegExExtraction("ID=",line)`)

**//EDIT:**

Thanks for your advices, did it now like this:

```
        public class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
        {
            public bool Equals(string line1, string line2)
            {
                return RegExExtraction("ID=", line1) == RegExExtraction("ID=", line2);
            }


            public int GetHashCode(string obj)
            {
                return RegExExtraction("ID=", obj).GetHashCode();
            }

            private string RegExExtraction(string value, string toCheck)
            {
                return Regex.Match(toCheck, string.Format("{0}({1}){2}", Regex.Escape(value), ".+?", Regex.Escape("|"))).Groups[1].Value;
            }
        }
newList = list2.Union(list1, new MyComparer()).ToList();
```

Comment: You can use `Concat` then `groupby` id

Comment: [Guidelines for Overriding Equals() and Operator ==](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(VS.90).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write your own `IEqualityComparer<>` (and by the way maybe a class that has properties for each value in your string).

By having that IEqualityComparer you could then call:

```
var distinctValues = new HashSet<MyClass>(list1.Concat(list2), MyClassEqualityComparer.Default);
```

And please **do not overwrite `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()`**. Always prefer an own implementation of `IEqualityComparer<>` and use this where you need your special comparision. Nearly every class or method that uses equality comparision has some overload that takes an `IEqualityComparer` as argument.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, got it now